# Can a ASP.NET web service support other protocols except Http?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am reading on internet about the difference between ASP.NET web service and WCF and have found that ASP.NET does not support any other protocol except `http` .
Can anyone please explain me the reason why ASP.NET web service don't support other transport protocols ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASMX web services are the original web service platform created as part of .NET 1.0. They are quite old, and the architecture is inflexible. In particular, they use the ASP.NET pipeline, which is focused on HTTP, not on multiple protocols.

They were replaced by WCF, which does not have these problems.

Comment: The pipeline and, in fact, the entire infrastructure. WCF does not depend on these, so it's able to use other protocols, and much more.

Answer (score 1):

It supports SOAP and other over-HTTP protocols. It is a design limitation, rectified with WCF.